# Acer Aspire V3-471G Network Controller is missing

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire

I have been using my Acer Aspire V3-471G for 2 years and suddenly the Network Controller is missing.

I tried Googling for ways to fix this and there is no changes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

How good are you with taking computers apart?

If it were me, the first thing I would do is open the laptop and re-seat the wifi card. It's a little guy that looks like this:

[image: wifi card pic]

Gently remove it, wipe the contacts with some rubbing alcohol using a q-tip. Make sure the antennae are connected, and then put it back in the computer how it was before you took it out.

If that doesn't work, you can scan for hardware changes in the device manager as described in this article (might want to try this first actually since it takes less effort):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/scan-for-recent-hardware-changesscanning-might-not/0f425026-1bf6-46ca-ae0b-2c2f51929e3c